Knowing a side, the inradius, and the circumradius of a triangle, find the other two sides
I need help with this easy triangle problem:

We know:

One of the sides a = 16 cm.
The inradius r = 6cm.
And the circumradius R = 17 cm.
That's all.

We must find the lengths of the other two sides.

I've got the values of the sin and cos of alpha (8/17 and 15/17, respectively) and yet I don't know how to make the system of equations.
I know this problem is far easier from all the others here (at least in comparison with what I have seen), but I am really stuck and need some assistance.

Do you know that $(ABC)=sr=\frac{abc}{4R}$?

Yeah but I don't know what can I get from it... I got b + c = 4/51(bc) - 16.

What is $\alpha$?

Let $\Delta$ be the area of the triangle and $s$ the semi-perimeter. Try using $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$ and $r=\frac \Delta s$. You can use Heron's formula for relating $a,b,c$ to $\Delta$. This is indeed a painful problem (I wouldn't recommend anyone doing this). For more formulas for $R$ and $r$ check out SL Loney's Trigonometry.

We don't know the value of alpha, just it's sin from 2R = a/sin(alpha).

But where is $\alpha$ ? Like on a drawing ?

Thank you @xyz1234! I will try to solve it this way and come back with the results.

There is no given drawing. That's also a problem.

I really don't understand your comment. You mean $\alpha$ could be any of the three angles in your triangle?

Well, we only know alpha is against the side a (which is 16cm).

I think there is more than one solution, perhaps the cosine could be negative.

$$\tan (\frac x2) = \frac{\sin (x)}{1+\cos(x)} \implies \tan (\frac{\alpha}2) = \frac{8}{17+15} = \frac1{4}$$
$$\tan(\frac{\alpha}2) = \frac r{s-a} \iff s-16 = 4 \cdot 6 \iff s = 40$$
$$a+b+c = 80 \implies b+c = 64$$
$$a^2 = b^2+c^2-2bc \cos (\alpha) \iff 256 = 64^2-2bc - 2bc \frac{15}{17}$$
$$2bc(\frac{32}{17}) = 64^2-16^2 = 80 \cdot 48 =16^2 \cdot 15 \iff bc = 60 \cdot 17$$
$$z^2 - 64z + 60 \cdot 17 = 0 \implies (z-32)^2 = 32^2-60 \cdot 17 = 4$$
$$z = 32 \pm 2 \implies b,c \in \{30,34\}$$

Thank you very much!!! Just to clarify, tan(x/2)=sin(x)/(1+cos(x)) and tan(α/2)=r/(s−a) are formulas right? And if so, where can I find more formulas like these?

yes those are famous identities, I'm not quite sure where there is a list of all of them, they are many
